# Haskell - implement empty, insert, member of Data.Set as Data.Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, insert, set

I have a problem. I am a Haskell beginner (4 weeks experience) and we´ve got the following task without ANY information about Set or Map. 
After searching a lot, I was finally able to figure out how the empty, insert and member function of Data.Map work.
For example:

```
insert 7 'x' (fromList [(5,'a'), (3,'b')]) == fromList [(3, 'b'), (5, 'a'), (7, 'x')]
```

But I have absolutely no idea how to implement it in the following code :(

I have already tried to implement the empty-function, hope it is right. At least I do not get a error so far.

Maybe someone can help me to implement the insert-function. So I have a example how it has to look like in Haskell - I think that would help me to implement "member" and "filter" by myself.

I tried something like :

```
insert k Set(Map.fromList[x]) = Set (Map.fromList [x,k])
```

but seems like that was totally *#*sd8*

```
module SetAsMap where

{-

Implemented a few operations on a 'Set a' as a newtype around a 'Map a ()'. 

-}

import Test.HUnit (runTestTT,Test(TestLabel,TestList),(~?=))

import Prelude hiding (filter)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map (Map)


-- | A 'Set' as a 'Map' to '()'.
newtype Set a = Set (Map a ())
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)


-- | An empty 'Set'.
empty :: (Ord a) => Set a
empty = Set (Map.fromList [])

-- | Insert and element into a 'Set'.
insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert = undefined

-- | Test if an element is in a 'Set'.
member :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Bool
member = error "Not yet implemented: menber"

-- | Filter all members that satisfy a predicate.
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set a
filter = error "Not yet implemented: filter"


-- | An example set used for testing.
testset :: Set Int
testset = insert 2 (insert 3 empty)

-- | Tests the implementations of the 'Set'.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    testresults <- runTestTT tests
    print testresults

-- | List of tests for the 'Set'.
tests :: Test
tests = TestLabel "ticTacToeTreeTests" (TestList [
    insert 2 testset ~?= testset,
    member 3 testset ~?= True,
    member 5 testset ~?= False,
    filter even testset ~?= insert 2 empty])
```

Edit:
THX for all your helpful postings!
I have those 4 functions now.

```
-- | An empty 'Set'.
empty :: Set a
empty = Set (Map.empty)

-- | Insert and element into a 'Set'.
insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert k (Set x) = Set (Map.insert k () x)

-- | Test if an element is in a 'Set'.
member :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Bool
member k (Set x) = (Map.member k x)

-- | Filter all members that satisfy a predicate.
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set a
filter f (Set x) = Set (Map.filter f x)
```

The empty, insert and member function seem to work (don`t get a error) but after implementing the filter function GHCi says this:

```
   Couldn't match type `a' with `()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for filter :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set a
          at SetAsMap.hs:35:11
    Expected type: () -> Bool
      Actual type: a -> Bool
    In the first argument of `Map.filter', namely `f'
    In the first argument of `Set', namely `(Map.filter f x)'
    In the expression: Set (Map.filter f x)
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Have you looked at the API for Data.Map (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html)?

Comment: First you need to find out about `Data.Map`. The docs that Benjamin lined to have example functions. Play with Data.Map for a while until you're used to it, then implementing Set with it will be much easier.

Comment: Ty! I edited my posting and it seems like there is just a little error left.

Comment: FYI, when you're looking for APIs, the best info is usually on Hackage. Note, however, that Hackage keeps lots of old versions of things around, so if you use Google you may land in an old version and need to jump up and down a bit to get to the current one. One great thing about Hackage is that you can usually jump straight from the documentation of a function to its source code, even if it is actually defined in a different package and re-exported.

Comment: `filter` filters associated values, not keys. Your associated values are all `()`. You want `filterWithKey` which takes a function which sees the key. ie: `filter f (Set x) = Set (Map.filterWithKey (\k _ -> f k)) x)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
insert k (Set map') = Set (Map.insert k () map')
```